# Counting nested arrays with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongoDB through mongoose in a node.js application.

In my db I have this general format:

Books:

```
BookSchema = {
variousData,
//Books contain pages
pages: [{type: pageSchema}]
}
```

Pages:

```
pageSchema = {
variousData,
//Pages contain frames
frames: [frameSchema]
}
```

Frames:

```
frameSchema = {
variousData
}
```

I want to write a count query that will count the total number of frames in all pages in all books.

So if I have this content in my db:

```
    Book1 = {
        data:data,
        pages: [
            {data:data,
             frames: [frame1,frame2,frame3]
            },
            {data:data,
                frames: [frame1,frame2,frame3]
            },
            {data:data,
                frames: [frame1,frame2,frame3]
            }
        ]
    }
```

and

```
    Book2 = {
        data:data,
        pages: [
            {data:data,
            frames: [frame1,frame2]
            },
            {data:data,
            frames: [frame1,frame2]
            },
            {data:data,
            frames: [frame1,frame2]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm expecting to get an end result of 15 (9 frames in book 1 and 6 frames in book 2)

All my attempts ended up with errors.

I can write a loop, but I feel like mongoose would have a better alternative.

Any suggestions?

Thanks all!

Comment: What are your attempts? Can you show us your code?

Comment: I've tried populating books with pages, and then populate the result with frames and then counting, but the population itself returns errors. It doesn't surprise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way would be like this:

```js
  Book.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
      "pages": { 
        "$map": {
          "input": "$pages",
          "as": "page",
          "in": { "$size": "$$page.frames" }
        }}
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$pages" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "pages": { "$sum": "$pages" }
    }}
  ],function(err,results) {

  })
```

Basically there the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator allows you to traverse the elements of the "pages" array, take a look at each "frames" array and return the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/size/). Now the content of "pages" is just an array of sizes for each "frames", and therefore the count.

Then all you really need to do is "add" those together. So you [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array and [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) all the page counts for each frame together with a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Comment: OK! so I copy pasted and then tried to understand what I was doing. Even with your explanation it wasn't an easy task but I think I got it! Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich If you want to "understand" then add each aggregation pipeline stage separately. First "project" then "project and unwind" and so on. That way yo can see what happens at every stage.